# Storing Date Calculations in SQL for use in SQL queries?

Tags: sql, date, query-optimization, converters, date-arithmetic

Can you store a convert date calculation in SQL and call it in some more efficient way than with a convert statement in SQL? Someone suspects that the date conversion may be slowing my query. I've heard there may be a way to optimize my query by removing nested calculations. My visceral sense is that this may not have any affect at all on my query but I really do need to find out.

```
SELECT TOP 10000 
SELECT SOMETABLE FROM THATDATABASE 
WHERE 
  (204 = SOMEIDENTIFIER) 
AND 
  (SOMETABLE.endDATE > convert(datetime3, '2014-01-09', 221)) 
AND 
  (SOMEIDENTIFIER > 0)
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  Have you looked at the query plan to determine where the actual bottleneck is?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "SELECT SOMECOLUMN FROM SOMETABLE"?

Comment: It will depend a great deal on which database you are using. In some versions of SQL (MySQL, most notably) nested calculations against an indexed column can cause a performance hit... cause the calculation itself cannot run against the index. Regardless, you'd need to tell us what database you're using and whether or not your endDate column is indexed

Comment: Just using a SQL 2013 database . Yes, it should have been Select somecolumn but type quickly and made it up on the fly. I will find out if the endDate is indexed.

Comment: There is no such things as a `SQL 2013` database....... are you using `mysql` ? `oracle`? `postgreSQL` ? IBM `db2` ? Microsoft `sql-server`? Or what else??

Comment: Sorry, that would be MS SQL-Server.